# How does Codeacademy work?

Tags: performance, unit-testing, automated-tests, code-testing

What to your opinion bases the mechanism behind Codeacademy? How do you use code in order to check if a few lines of code are serving a certain purpose, in a certain wanted way?

I'm not looking for a concrete way of implementing such a thing, I was just wondering what languages/technologies are possibly involved with a mechanism like that.

Comment: I believe they compile the code and run it with their own code to see if it worked properly.

Comment: Yeah I assume, but what parameters are being compared? Output and that's it?